# How pass data to popup window which created used div

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, popupwindow

I have table in my page with name and price product. Near only row there is a button "Make order". When I click it I get a popup window. I must pass my name and price to this popup.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(state){
    document.getElementById('window').style.display = state;
    document.getElementById('wrap').style.display = state;
}
</script>

<div onclick="show('none')" id="wrap"></div>

<!-- Popup Window -->
<div id="window">
<img class="close" onclick="show('none')" src="/images/close.png">
<form   onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" action="/user/confirmOrder">
    <p>Address:</p>
    <input type="text" name="address">
    <p>Count:</p>
    <input type="text" id="count" name="count">
    <p id='err_count' class='error'></p>

    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name}">
    <br>
    NameProduct:
    <input type="text" id="nameProduct" name="nameProduct">
    <input type="text" id="priceProduct" name="priceProduct">
    <input type="submit" value="Make order">
</form>
</div>



<table border="2px">
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Price</th>
</tr>
<c:forEach items="${productList}" var="product" varStatus="status">
<tr>
    <td> ${product.getProductName()}</td>
    <input type="hidden" id="productName" name="productName"     value=${product.getProductName()}>
    <td>${product.getPrice()}</td>
    <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" name="productPrice" value=${product.getPrice()}>
    <td>
       <button class="myButton" onclick="show('block')">Make Order</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

How can I pass to my popup window name and price chosen row? Early on I used `window.open()` and it worked, but now I use div for creating the popup window.

Comment: I click on my button `<button class="myButton" onclick="show('block')">Make Order</button>`

Comment: My popup's window id is `<div id="window">`

Comment: there's another problem with your existing code, your <c:forEach> creates multiple hidden fields with the same ID, "productName" and "productPrice" repeatedly, It'll cause a lot of problems. The Id should be unique for each element. Two or more elements can never have the same id.

Comment: Yes, but  there is table  and every button is only one row

Comment: Do you mean that there's only going to be a single row in your table? because only then would it work .

Comment: No, there are many rows in my table . Maybe I don't understand something .. 
So I can do it only with window.open(), yes?

Comment: you can do it either ways but window.open() would be a better way of doing it. Also keep in mind the Id should be unique for each element. Two or more elements can never have the same id.

Comment: Ok, I will use window.open for it . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the popup window this way

```
var childWindow=window.open("windowUrl");
```

You then either need to create a function in the child window that sets the name, price, and chosen row and then call that function this way in the parent window.

```
childWindow.setterFunction(name,price,chosenRow);
```

Or, you could create global variables (not recommended ) in the child window for name, price, and chosen row and then set them from the parent window like this

```
childWindow.Name =name;
childWindow.Price = price;
childWindow.chosenRow = chosenRow;
```

Comment: Thanks , I  created popup window used window.open() , it worked.
But now I create window using div tags , how can I pass data now ?